# reactive forms not bind dropdown if no interaction with form in angular

Tags: angular, binding, dropdown, boilerplate, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form include 3 dropdowns, this dropdown get their data from API
The problem is the dropdown does not bind data if I don't click on dropdown (blur on any filed in form )

my HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="dropdownsForm" novalidate class="needs-validation">
<div class="dropdown">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="CountryName" 
                [attr.data-live-search]="true" style="width: 150px;" >
                <option *ngFor="let Country of allCountrys" [value]="Country.id">
                  {{Country.title}}</option>
              </select>
</div>
</form>
```

My ts

```
allCountrys: DropDownListForLkpsDto[];

 constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private _countryService: CountryServiceProxy
  ) {

  }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.dropdownsForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        CountryName: [""],
      }
    );


    this._countryService.getAllCountrysForDDl().subscribe(result => {
      this.allCountrys = result;

    });
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the use of async pipe in your code to achieve what you want (you aren't unsubscribing either) , read more about it here:
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: @HellaSpace Thanks for your replay, it works fine, but what If I need to add some code in subscribe after I assign the result to my list (Which is the real case in my scenario)

Comment: You can unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy which is the usually the most common way to go around it, have a look at Solution #1 here:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days of search, we finally find the issue
in my ts file, I have this line
`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`
into my
`@Component({ })`
when we remove changeDetection line it works fine